# Prospect mail 0.5.1 attachments not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, email

After the recent update on Prospect Mail 0.5.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, attachments from `Browse Computer` is no longer working.

```
Error: The following files couldn't be attached: FILENAME HERE. Please try again later.
```